# SSL Issue : Firebase Issued different domain certificate to my custom domain

Tags: firebase, ssl, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I'm having hard time in understanding how the SSL part of this firebase works
as there is no option to change
and its causing many issues if we use other SSL apart from firebase
is there any way where we can disable firebase ssl
and use custom one
or can some one tell me how to reset  this ssl issued by firebase (which is different domain and its just partial not full/strict https)

Answer (score 2):

The SSL certificates Firebase Hosting uses come from letsentrypt.org. They are full SSL certificates, but they are shared between many domains. From the Firebase documentation on its [SSL certificate provisioning](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#ssl-provisioning):

> Your domain will be listed as one of the Subject Alternative Names (SAN) in the FirebaseApp SSL certificate. You can view this certificate using the browser's security tools. While the domain is provisioning, you might see an invalid certificate that does not include your domain name. This is a normal part of the process and will resolve after your domain's certificate is available.

If your project is on the paid Blaze plan, you can reach out to Firebase support to set up a SSL certificate you provide on Firebase Hosting for it.

Comment: In that case the rest of my answer still applies: you'll be on a shared certificate, which may take up to 24 hours to settle and properly show as secured in the browser. If you think you're having a security issue not covered by that, I recommend editing your question to explicitly say/show what the problem is.

Comment: Are you saying if we reach out to Firebase Support, we can set up a custom SSL certificate? I didn't find any documentation on this